# Wp7 Listbox subitems NEED assistance

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

Basically I'm making this simple note app and i have a listbox. When the user adds a note via clicking the save button, the note saves as a .txt file and in the listbox, it shows the note. So now if the user wants to make changes etc, they can just click the listbox item which will be the name of the note they saved. What i want to do is basically when the user clicks save, it saves and it shows the name of the note in the listbox so e.g. note name is test.txt then in the listbox test.txt appears. just under the item name which appears in the listbox, how can i add a sort of subitem? e.g. like the mail in wp7. It has the subject of the email and the subitem which shows the first 12 or so words. How can i do this with my app? soo far i only got the note name. I want it to show the name AND the first 14 words of the message under the item. I hope this makes sense.

my code soo far:

This basically adds the items inside myNote folderto the listbox so it displays the saved notes.

```
Dim myIsolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("myNote")
    Dim directory As String = "./myNote/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames(directory)
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = filenames
```

This is the xml for the listbox

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" x:Name="ListBox1" Width="440" SelectionMode="Single" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#00000000" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" />
```

Anyone? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add somes text below your file title in each listbox item, you need to define a new [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for your ListBox. By defining your own [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx), you will be able to choose exactly how each listbox item are displayed.

Here is a small sample with the provided `Listbox`, the template (everything that is contained in the `DataTemplate` section) is very simple, it's up to you to customize it by changing colors, fonts and so on...

In your xaml page :

```
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,8" x:Name="ListBox1"
                 Width="440" SelectionMode="Single"
                 FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="2"
                 Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
                 Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#00000000"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
                 ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Then you need to assign to `ItemsSource` a new type of `List`. Instead of just assigning a filenames `List` (which is a `List` of `String`), you have to provide a `List` of a something such as :

```
Public Class NewListItem
    Public Property FileName() As String
        Get
            Return m_FileName
        End Get
        Set
            m_FileName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FileName As String
    Public Property Content() As String
        Get
            Return m_Content
        End Get
        Set
            m_Content = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Content As String
End Class
```

So basically, it's just a data structure containing 2 properties : `FileName` and `Content`.

Finally, you need to build your new type of `List` by iterating through your filenames `List` and filling your new properties with proper values (of course, it's just pseudo-code) :

```
Dim newList As New List(Of NewListItem)()
For Each file As var In filenames
    Dim item As New NewFileItem()
    item = file
    ' open the file the way you want
    ' extract the 14 first characters the way you want
    Dim content As String = InlineAssignHelper(item.Content, content)
    newList.Add(item)
Next
ListBox1.ItemsSource = filenames
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm having one problem.

in this section:

Dim newList As New List(Of NewListItem)()
    For Each file As var In filenames
        Dim item As New NewFileItem()
        item = file
        
        Dim content As String = InlineAssignHelper(item.Content, content)
        newList.Add(item)
    Next
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = filenames
where it says: "For Each file As var In filenames"

I get an error saying "type "var" is not defined". I'm unable to test the code and this seems really good? have any idea why im getting this?

Comment: I'm no VB .NET expert, but i think you should change "For Each file As var In filenames" into "For Each file As String In filenames" and do not forget that i only provided pseudo-code (it is not intended to compile, just to ease the understanding). The "filenames" list should be the one provided in your question (Dim filenames As String() = myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames(directory)). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that but one problem led to another :( now it for:  

Dim item As New NewFileItem()
            item = file
            ' open the file the way you want
            ' extract the 14 first characters the way you want
            Dim content As String = InlineAssignHelper(item.Content, content)
            newList.Add(item)

NewFileItem is not defined and InlineAssignHelper is not declared.

Comment: Apparently, "NewFileItem" if defined in your project, is out of reach. It could be a namespace issue, an accessor issue (not declared in Public?) and many other things. The same applies for your "InlineAssignHelper" method. Being not a VB .NET developper, i was just answering your WP7/XAML question. For all the rest regarding VB .NET (language references, compilation issues), i let you create a new question if needed, improving your chances to get a better answer ;)